# Flutter iOS App Size issue: Runner.app size is ~450MB. Can anyone help how can this be reduced?

Tags: flutter, ipa, flutter-ios

I have tried almost all the solutions available online. People has suggested to change flutter version to stable, clean the target etc.. but I am not able to reduce the Runner.app size so far with any of these solutions.

Note - In "Runner.app/Frameworks/Flutter.framework" folder there is one file named "Flutter" which is occupying 383MB of space.

Can anyone help me knowing how this can be reduced?

Diawi is not allowing me to upload that big file in order to get it installed using bar code & link.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

you are not supposed to commit/push `.../Flutter.framework` folder to repo. So its size shouldn't matter, because it is dynamically generated in local dev env.

Answer (score 0):

Try to run the command `flutter clean` on the terminal, then run the app again.
This action worked for me.